# Green screen When calling PhotoCaptureDevice API on Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I don't know why, occasionally, my phone's camera will turning Green screen when calling PhotoCaptureDevice API, other camera apps and even build-in camera app all doesn't work, and then I have to restart the phone to fix the Green screen problem. In addtion, it should be noted there are no Exception was thrown out during the Green screen status. I searched this problem on Google.com, seemed that it's a WP8 OS fault.

Here, I want to ask:
1). Is there have a way to avoid or reduce the Green screen issue?
2). Due to no Exception, how to detect the Green screen status programmatically? (Then I can show a message to remind user restart his phone.)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are using the PhotoCaptureDevice class.
Try disposing your camera object, call GC.Collect() once you are done taking the picture.
I think this will help you get rid of the green screen issue. I had read that this GC.Collect() resolves the green screen issue in some Microsoft forum. Don't exactly remember where. But having said that,using GC.Collect() in programs is generally not a good practice.

Hope you get it working. Thanks.